# Anaconda: An unexpected error ocurred on Navigator start-up

Tags: anaconda

I had installed Anaconda, I had managed to launch it and then use R or python, and today I can no longer launch it and I get this error (I get the same error when I run the software in administrator mode)

```
An unexpected error ocurred on Navigator start-up
psutil.AccesDenied(pid=5740)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil\_pswindows.py", line 620, in wrapper
return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil\_pswindows.py", line 690, in cmdline
ret = cext.proc_cmdline(self.pid)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access Denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\exceptions.py", line 75, in exception_handler
return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 108, in start_app
if misc.load_pid() is None: # A stale lock might be around
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\misc.py", line 384, in load_pid
cmds = process.cmdline()
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 701, in cmdline
return self._proc.cmdline()
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil\_pswindows.py", line 623, in wrapper
raise AccessDenied(self.pid, self._name)
psutil.AccessDenied: psutil.AccessDenied (pid=5740)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the anaconda in win10 x64 (python3.x) and I got this problem this morning as well. All the things had been done in anaconda was that I installed a package called pywinauto, then I turned off the computer and went home.

I follow the suggestion from https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/4hBTDOcDzgo by lan, I update the anaconda by using the command.

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

However, the error occurred the same.

Then I reboot the computer and restart the anaconda, magic thing happens! the anaconda works fine!

I think maybe some configuration has been changed when I install the new package, and this change is conflicted with the current configuration which you need to reboot the computer to fix it. you should note that turn off computer then restart it is not equal to reboot it.

So, just reboot the computer and it will be fine.

Comment: Restart and Uninstalling Anaconda and also python didn't correct my problem either

Answer (score 4):

I follow the suggestions:
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6006
,
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1984

These commands helped me:

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
conda update navigator-updater
anaconda-navigator --reset
```

Comment: Worked for me, didn't need to restart.

Answer (score 2):

Facing the same error initially, I tried other solutions given here by executing the commands in anaconda terminal but nothing works in my case as I was getting the following error on executing command

> Load Error: invalid yaml at position 0

This means ***.condarc*** file is either corrupted due to some reason or there may be some changes in it.
The solution that worked for me is to delete ***.condarc***. As the ***.condarc*** configuration file follows simple YAML syntax.
***.condarc*** is automatically created in your home directory the time you run anaconda navigator.

**Conda** will re-create it, again.

Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 2):

Try removing .condarc from your directory and check if it works. I had the same issue and it worked for me. I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had same Problem , when i tried to update the anaconda navigator, there was conda memory error...Finally,Simple Reset Command Worked for me...!!

```
anaconda-navigator --reset
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above solutions are not work,just turn off the proxy.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBB6m.png)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.I used the v2ray and proxyfier throught the connect internet.Then I exit the proxyfier and v2ray and reopen the anaconda navigator.finally slove the problem.