# Anaconda navigator start error

Tags: python, anaconda

when I run anaconda navigator, it shows the output as follows:

```
An unexpected error occurred on Navigator start-up pautil.AccessDenied(pid=797)
```

how to solve it? thanks

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329455/anaconda-an-unexpected-error-ocurred-on-navigator-start-up).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anaconda: An unexpected error ocurred on Navigator start-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329455/anaconda-an-unexpected-error-ocurred-on-navigator-start-up)