# Anaconda prompt closing fast

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, spyder

screenshot of prompt before it closes:

[image]

The anaconda prompt closes automatically not sure why. pic of anaconda files after install files installed:

[image]

I installed the anaconda distrubtion from [here](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section) version 3.7. I cannot find anaconda app, spyder or jupyter notebook app. I only see files named after them. I tryed uninstalling but to clean out anaconda and properly install again i have been told to remove files left behind when using normal uninstall. So Is there a way to run [anaconda-clean](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-clean) without anaconda prompt? Im a newb at coding .

i cannot type anything into the prompt it shows me the picture above before quickly closing.

following someones advice i did the below not sure where to go from here?

i did the "start C:\ etc to _conda.exe info" and it gave me this prompt which closed again very quickly

```
ConfigurationLoaderror: unable to load configuration file
path: C:\Users\Name\.condarc
reason: invalid yaml at position 0
```

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54673761/4518341) the solution to the condarc problem is to delete `.condarc`, though you'll probably want to back it up first if you've customized it. Hope that helps. I don't use Conda myself, and I'm not sure what the root issue is.

Comment: Open a "Command Prompt" window yourself (Win+R, `cmd.exe`) and type `C:\Users\Muneeb\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\Muneeb\Anaconda3\ `   That's the command that the "Anaconda Prompt" shortcut should be running. 
If it doesn't work, then at least you'll be able to copy-paste the whole error message.

Comment: @wjandrea  i have searched for the .condarc file and have attempted to delete it through file explorer and it gives me the error " item not found this item is no longer located in c:\users\muneeb "

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and below **three** steps solved the problem for me. Note: I faced this issue on Windows 10 and I referred [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/command-prompt-cmd-flashes-but-does-not-stay-open/f695ad86-cbd7-459b-9289-778c2b313140) post from Microsoft to resolve my issue.

**Step 1.** In the start menu type regedit to search and choose **Registry Editor** App.

**Step 2.** Click on **Edit** in the menu bar at the top. Then click on **Find** to find  `autorun`
[image]

**Step 3.** Delete the `autorun` file present in **Command Processor** folder.

[image]